# Give a concrete description of all open balls in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the endowed with the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}$. Give a concrete description of all open balls in $\mathbb{Z}$.

My attempt: Let $x$ be an integer. Then $B(x, r)= \{x\}$ for $r\in (0,1]$, $B(x, r)= \{x-1,x,x+1\}$ for $r\in (0,2]$, $B(x, r)= \{x-2,x-1,x,x+1,x+2\}$ for $r\in (0,3]$, etc.

So, my answer is $B(x, r)= \{x-(k-1), x-(k-2), \cdots, x-1,x,x+1,\cdots, x-(k+1)\}$ for $r\in (0,k]$.

Is it correct?

Comment: $r$ may be in $(0,1]$ as well as $(0,2]$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your answer has a  contradiction in iteself. You should say $B(x, r)= \{x-(k-1), x-(k-2), \cdots, x-1,x,x+1,\cdots, x+k-1\}$ for $r\in (k-1,k]$.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have understood my mistake.